# TensorFlow: Changing the maximum number of checkpoints to keep when training using a Supervisor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

There is a `max_to_keep` property in a saver that allows one to choose how many checkpoints to keep. When I create a default saver with `max_to_keep` as two and pass this saver to the supervisor, somehow the default number of 5 continues to appear. Is there a way to tell the supervisor to limit the number of checkpoints to 2?

The arguments passed on to the Supervisor has no such ability, I believe, according to the documentation here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Supervisor is a small wrapper around a Coordinator, a Saver, and a SessionManager. Try to use them separately, not using a wrapper.